# error TS2322: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'labels' does not exist in type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a problem that I can not explain.

I create an angular service with the interface implementation but it tells me that I have an error that I can not explain.

```
error TS2322: Type '{ labels: string[]; datasets: { data: number[]; backgroundColor: string[]; hoverBackgroundColor: string[]; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'DataBase[]'.
```

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'labels' does not exist in type 'DataBase[]'.

this my code :

**Interface.ts**

```
export interface Dashboardtwidget {
  title: string;
  widgetType: string;
  datatype: DataBase[];
}

export interface DataBase {
 labels: string[];
 datasets: {
 data: number[];
 backgroundColor: string[];
 hoverBackgroundColor: string[]
};
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Dashboardtwidget} from '../models/dashboard';


@Injectable()
 export class DashboardService {
  data: Dashboardtwidget[] = [
  {
    title: 'Widget 1',
    widgetType: 'cardStyle1',
    datatype: {
      labels: ['A','B','C'],
      datasets: [
        {
         data: [300, 50, 100],
         backgroundColor: [
          '#FF6384',
          '#36A2EB',
          '#FFCE56'
         ],
         hoverBackgroundColor: [
          '#FF6384',
          '#36A2EB',
          '#FFCE56'
        ]
       }]
    }
  }
  }
```

Has anyone ever had this problem and this error message?

Because I do not see where the problem comes from

Comment: Post a function in which the error occurs... In short you're trying assign an object to an array of objects.

Comment: As far as I understood you trying to assign `DataBase` to `DataBase[]`. Object to array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datasets` in `DataBase` looks like an `Array` type when you've declared it as an Object type.

Change your `DataBase` interface to this:

```
export interface Dashboardtwidget {
  title: string;
  widgetType: string;
  datatype: DataBase[];
}

interface Dataset {
  data: number[];
  backgroundColor: string[];
  hoverBackgroundColor: string[];
}

export interface DataBase {
  labels: string[];
  datasets: Dataset[];
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6tuzg8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard.service.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks for the solution !